# express response empty without key

Tags: javascript, express

I am sending a result back as res.json(data).

What's weird is that from Postman as well as just localhost, I get just a pair of brackets like this: [].

But when I do this:

```
res.send(data['someKey'])
```

I do get a value.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you describe what `data` variable holds?

Comment: Just a string or float. Data is actually a decently sized JSON with many values.

Comment: Can you try JSON.stringify(data) and see if it works?

Comment: Still nothing. Just brackets [ ]

Comment: res.json() runs JSON.stringify() internally so that is why it is not working.  It looks like there is problem with the data object.

Comment: Whew... I figured it out. I was appending key value pairs to empty brackets, not to empty curly braces.